# JNDI tree: custom work manager vs. default work manager

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic, weblogic12c

I have created a global scoped custom work manager 'WorkManagerHighPrio' via Weblogic console.
Default work manager 'default' is listed in the JNDI tree and its reference is able to be looked up via `java:global/wm/default`. I wonder why my custom work manager is not listed in the JNDI tree, moreover the lookup URL is `java:comp/env/wm/WorkManagerHighPrio`.

`java:global` vs. `java:comp/env`

I checked in `config.xml`, both work managers are configured similarly:

```xml
    <work-manager>
      <name>default</name>
      <target>app01_cluster</target>
      <min-threads-constraint>default_MinThreads</min-threads-constraint>
      <max-threads-constraint>default_MaxThreads</max-threads-constraint>
      <ignore-stuck-threads>false</ignore-stuck-threads>
    </work-manager>
    <work-manager>
      <name>WorkManagerHighPrio</name>
      <target>app01_cluster</target>
    </work-manager>
```

I need the custom work manager to be bounded in java:global/wm, as I need this work manager inside the resource adapter.

```java
WorkManager wm = (WorkManager) ic.lookup("java:global/wm/default");
```

Inside the resource adapter application, I managed to retrieve reference of default workmanager via lookup, even though I get the next problem:

```
weblogic.work.j2ee.J2EEWorkManager cannot be cast to javax.resource.spi.work.WorkManager
```

I thought, if I lookup a work manager inside ra, it will automatically converted to `javax.resource.spi.work.WorkManager`, but I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The "WorkManager" class you have to use is:  `commonj.work.WorkManager`.

As mentioned in the docs:

> Work Manager API
>
> The Work Manager API, commonj.work, provides a set of interfaces that
> allows an application to execute multiple work items concurrently
> within a container.

There is a simple "Work Manager Example" there too:

https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12212/wls/COMMJ/using_commonj.htm#GUID-72F860BE-9315-417E-B406-2C1ED17CE87F